# Fingerprint reader HP Envy X360 13 - recognises the reader, but cannot use in 20.10

Tags: hp, fingerprint-reader

I just replaced an aging HP Spectre X360 with an HP Envy X360 Ryzen 5. Everything works fine, except for the fingerprint reader. Following is the error:

```
failed to claim fingerprint device Synaptics Sensors: Open failed with error: The driver encountered a protocol error with the device
```

The HP site does not provide any info or drivers. Searching the net, I see similar problems with different machines, but no solutions. Is there anywhere I need to be looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recent HP Envy X360 notebooks ship with a *touch-style* fingerprint reader, which is not compatible with the Synaptics software just yet. Unfortunately, only swipe-style fingerprint readers can be used at this time. Hopefully this will not always be the case.

Comment: Thanks Matigo - that clarifies - I'll just wait till it arrives/or accept having to log in with a password (woe is me, dealing with these first world problems). Appreciate your clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, click on *Users* and click on *Fingerprint login* and there you go.

Comment: Hi Amshuman - thanks - but that is exactly where the error is presented. However, Matigo has clarified that this particular fingerprint reader is not (yet) supported. - Cjeers!