# Can't setup fingerprint authentication on HP ENVY x360

Tags: hp, authentication, fingerprint-reader

Currently running Ubuntu 22.04.2* LTS.
Clearly there's a fingerprint device on my machine:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c4c Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
```

And after I run the command:

```
sudo service fprintd status
```

I get the following message telling me that the service is currently active and running:

```
● fprintd.service - Fingerprint Authentication Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fprintd.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-03-07 20:35:26 WET; 9s ago
       Docs: man:fprintd(1)
   Main PID: 4381 (fprintd)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 18842)
     Memory: 1.5M
        CPU: 51ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/fprintd.service
             └─4381 /usr/libexec/fprintd

HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-15-es1xxx systemd[1]: Starting Fingerprint Authentication Daemon...
HP-ENVY-x360-Convertible-15-es1xxx systemd[1]: Started Fingerprint Authentication Daemon.
```

But when I run the final command to setup the fingerprint:

```
fprintd-enroll -f right-index-finger
```

I get the following error message:

```
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm open to providing more information if required.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312168/fingerprint-reader-hp-envy-x360-13-recognises-the-reader-but-cannot-use-in-20?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fingerprint reader HP Envy X360 13 - recognises the reader, but cannot use in 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312168/fingerprint-reader-hp-envy-x360-13-recognises-the-reader-but-cannot-use-in-20)

Comment: @guiverc I mistakenly wrote 20.04.2 LTS. The correct Ubuntu version I'm using is 22.04.2. LTS

Answer (score 2):

The link in the question comments are a bit outdated — I was able to get this to work for my HP Envy with the same fingerprint reader and Ubuntu 22.04.

I posted this in response to [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1276566/fingerprint-reader-on-ubuntu-20-04-at-hp-envy-17m-cg0013dx/1485462#1485462):

Per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1445458/ubuntu-22-04-fingerprint-sensor-04f30c4c-elan-microelectronics-corp-hp-envy), the drivers for this device are now available, but require building `libfprint` from source, using [this fork](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geodic/libfprint/-/tree/elanmoc2).

```
sudo apt-get install meson ninja-build libgusb-dev libgirepository1.0-dev libnss3-dev libgudev-1.0-dev gtk-doc-tools valgrind
sudo ldconfig
git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geodic/libfprint.git
cd libfprint/
git checkout elanmoc2
git pull
meson build
cd build
ninja
sudo ninja install
```

If you have not already done so, you will also need to install `libpam-fprintd` to be able to use the reader to login.

[You may need to reset your fingerprint reader in the BIOS](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/geodic/libfprint/-/issues/1)  — I could not verify my right index finger until I reset the reader, but all my other fingerprints worked. To reset the reader, enter the BIOS, look under Security, and enable “Fingerprint Reset on Reboot”. Select “Yes” when asked to verify that you want to reset the reader — you will lose all current fingerprint data — and allow the computer to reboot. The BIOS setting will reset to “No”, so you do not need to re-enter the BIOS.

Now you can login and add fingerprints using Settings/Users or `fprintd-enroll -f <finger>`.